# How to keep a copy of all Transactions core data

Tags: core-data

I have a booking system in Core Data, and I have a Transaction entity which at the moment has a relationship with Appointment, along with some other things. An Appointment can be made by a Client. And an appointment has a relationship with a Service type.

I want to store all transactions made on the computer, however if a client is deleted I still want the past transactions of the client to show. Likewise, if an appointment or service is deleted I still want it to show up in the past transactions. Also any modifications made to the service name shouldn't change in the transaction, although any modifications to the client name should be changed within the transaction.

How can this be achieved? I know that it's possible to put a "delete" attribute in every entity rather than actually deleting an entity, but then if modifications are made within a service for example, the change will be reflected in the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compliance is an issue you could keep multiple copies of your entities. With a creation timestamp you would have a pretty good unique id to identify them (in combination with another property or with your own ID scheme).

Now, instead of modifying any transaction, create a new one with the same creation date and copying all the data (but a different timestamp in a `modifiedDate` property). When displaying them, just display the latest version. When deleting, just mark as deleted.

Comment: Is there any need to have a createdDate property, if you have a modifiedDate property?

Comment: I think that would make it quite fool-proof. You can compare the creation date to make sure that this is the same `transaction`. The modified date would always be different. If you have an alternative ID scheme, you can also do without the creation date.